# Angular 2/4 Event click button created in component

Tags: angular

I would like to create a dynamic button "Favoris" with a click event "onListFavorisAdded()" in a ng-table for each row. The table is created and configured in the component. So I create this button in the component.ts too and after I put this in the html. The button is display in my web page but the event doesn't work when I click on it...

html :

```
<ng-table [config]="config"
              (tableChanged)="refreshTable(config)"
              (expanderClicked)="expanderClicked($event)"
              [rows]="rows" [columns]="columns"
              [expandable]="true"
              [expandedComponent]="rowComponent"
              [rowInputs]="rowInputs">
    </ng-table>
```

the function which creat the rows in my component :  I do a for for each row which are creating in the table

```
for (let collab of collaborators) {
      // Add a column name
      collab.nomPrenom = this.getData(collab, "data.personne.nom", "").toUpperCase() + " " + this.getData(collab, "data.personne.prenom", "");

      // Add a column preview
      collab.preview = '<a class="btn-default" href="#/profile/' + this.getData(collab, "tgi") + '" aria-label="Profile">  <i class="fa fa-eye" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>';

      // !!!!! Add a column Favoris !!!!!!!!
      collab.favoris = '<button data-ng-click="onListFavorisAdded()"><i class="fa fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>';
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: are you using any library

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is make an table with an ngFor in it:

```
<table>
    <tr>
       <td *ngFor="let dataRow of Data; let i = index" (click)="onListFavorisAdded()">{{dataRow.name}}</td>
```

Each item you add in the **Data** array will make a new row.

Comment: I can do this in a ng-table directly ?

Comment: @L.M I have no clue what ngTable does. You have to figure that out on your own.

Comment: ng-table create the table with the configuration and element defined in the component